# Eclipse STS 4 Error: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

I got following error on my latest version of Eclipse STS 4.

> Could not find or load main class
>   com.infoflow.report.ReportApplication

here is my STS Version:

> Spring Tool Suite 4
>   Version: 4.5.1.RELEASE
>
> Build Id: 202001211336

My Spring Version

> 2.0.6.RELEASE

I have tried following actions but seem no luck yet:

1. Re-Import the Project
2. Maven Clean / Project Clean
3. Change the JRE to JDK
4. List item

Any help regarding this would be very appreciated.

Comment: can you show pom.xml or build.gradle

Comment: here https://pastebin.com/EVZV4DrM

Comment: Switched back to STS 3 solved the issue, maybe STS 4 is not stablle/ready yet to use.

Comment: This is more of spring boot version compatibility with sts, maven plugin failed to work properly so either use compatible version of spring boot or change the sts which you did.

Comment: so it means  that my Spring  project version is no longger supported by the STS 4 right?

Comment: To check which all version support create a demo spring boot application in sts and see the drop down.

Comment: thanks for the info mate, that's help alot

Comment: The Spring Tools 4 themselves should work on various Spring Boot versions and there is no specific minimum version that you need in your project in order to allow the IDE to work with it. In case the Maven integration in Eclipse fails for your project, that could indeed happen, especially around specific versions of Maven plugins that you use and specific JDK versions (referring to the JDK that is used to run the IDE itself).

Comment: @YusufIbrahim What Eclipse version is this STS based on?
For Eclipse 2019-12 there is an active issue that causes this exception due to long classpath: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=558495

Comment: There are many possible reasons for an error like that. One possibility is this Eclipse bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=558495 which affected windows when project has a lot of dependencies. Also discussed here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/406 . Your problem may be something else, but this is still a good candidate.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check issues:

[STS issue 406](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/406)

[STS issue 407](https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/407)

Apparently the problem solved in nightly build

http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/STS4/nightly-distributions.html

I have the same problem and testing the solution proposed in issue